# Display product price based on quantity in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

How to display Product price based on 12 quantity in woocommerce shop page.

[image]

```
function sv_change_product_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    $unit_price = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'unit_price', true );
    if ( ! empty( $unit_price ) ) {
        $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( $unit_price ) . ' inc GST per bottle</span>'; 
    }

    return $price_html;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sv_change_product_html', 10, 2 );


function sv_change_product_price_cart( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

      $unit_price = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], 'unit_price', true );
    if ( ! empty( $unit_price ) ) {
        $price = wc_price( $unit_price ) . ' inc GST per bottle';   
    }
    return $price;

}   

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'sv_change_product_price_cart', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit outdated since WooCommerce 3 (and your question a bit unclear)… Try the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'displayed_product_unit_price', 10, 2 );
function displayed_product_unit_price( $price_html, $product ) {
    if ( $unit_price = $product->get_meta( 'unit_price' ) ) {
        $price_html  = '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( floatval( $unit_price ) ) . ' ' . __( "inc GST per bottle", "woocommerce") . '</span><br>';
        $price_html .= '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( floatval( $unit_price ) * 12 ) . ' ' . __( "inc GST per 12-bottles", "woocommerce") . '</span>';
    }
    return $price_html;
}



add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'displayed_cart_item_unit_price', 10, 3 );
function displayed_cart_item_unit_price( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( $unit_price = $cart_item['data']->get_meta( 'unit_price' ) ) {
        $price = wc_price( floatval( $unit_price ) ) . ' ' . __( "inc GST per bottle", "woocommerce");
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

[image]

Now if the WooCommerce product active price (by default) is based on 12 bottles, you should replace the following line *(in the first function)*:

```
$price_html .= '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( floatval( $unit_price ) * 12 ) . ' ' . __( "inc GST per 12-bottles", "woocommerce") . '</span>';
```

by this line:

```
$price_html .= '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) ) . ' ' . __( "inc GST per 12-bottles", "woocommerce") . '</span>';
```